# If Functions with multiple conditions in excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

I’m having difficulties with this function/array.

```
{=IF(ROWS(A9:A$9)<=A$1,INDEX(Tracker!C:C,SMALL(IF(Tracker!$C$3:$C$9965=A$2,Tracker!$R$3:$R$9965=A$3,ROW(Tracker!$C$3:$C$9965)),ROWS(A9:A$9))),"")}
```

(and yes, I made it an array with the ‘<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>’ )

Basically, I need to add another condition to this. I’ve tried several different methods, but none seem to like my syntax. What it’s doing is searching for one condition in a specific column then I need to add another condition to in another row before it displays the indicated cell.
What you see above is a function that does work, but with only one condition. All I need to do is make it have another condition before it does what it does now. That's all. Any help? Idea's? Even a presentation on how it put together and why. I love learning so give it to me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{=IF(AND(ROWS(A9:A$9)<=A$1,"Second Condition"),INDEX(Tracker!C:C,SMALL(IF(Tracker!$C$3:$C$9965=A$2,Tracker!$R$3:$R$9965=A$3,ROW(Tracker!$C$3:$C$9965)),ROWS(A9:A$9))),"")}
```

Different formatting for viewing:

```
{=IF(
    AND(
        ROWS(A9:A$9)<=A$1,
        "Second Condition"
        ),
    INDEX(
        Tracker!C:C,
        SMALL(
            IF(
                Tracker!$C$3:$C$9965=A$2,
                Tracker!$R$3:$R$9965=A$3,
                ROW(Tracker!$C$3:$C$9965)
                ),
            ROWS(A9:A$9)
            )
        ),
    "")}
```

Comment: Its just blank. I put in the code and left the Second condition blank. No error, just blank. All the ref cells are correct. This should have worked, I don't get it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what you tried (don't delete anything in your original post, just add it at the bottom).